# Grouping selectors into one category with jQuery

Tags: jquery, grouping, css-selectors, simplify

I am going to have 20 "groups" like these:

```
$("#checkbox-apple").click(function(){
    $("#graphic-apple").toggle();
}) 

$("#checkbox-orange").click(function(){
    $("#graphic-orange").toggle();
}) 

$("#checkbox-pineapple").click(function(){
    $("#graphic-pineapple").toggle();
})
```

Instead of copying each group and changing two words, how would I be able to shorten my code greatly by having any checkbox toggle its equivalent graphic, something along the lines of this code?:

```
$("#checkbox" FRUIT).click(function(){
    $("#graphic" FRUIT).toggle();
})
```

Comment: You could assign a particular css class to all of them and then get the substring

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Give them a common class (not *necessary*, but useful -- below I'm using "fruit") and then it's a simple string operation:

```
$(".fruit").click(function() {
    $("#graphic-" + this.id.replace("checkbox-", "")).toggle();
});
```

(Or maybe they already have some other common feature you could use.)

Or if you don't add a class:

```
$("#checkbox-apple, #checkbox-orange, #checkbox-pineapple").click(function() {
    $("#graphic-" + this.id.replace("checkbox-", "")).toggle();
});
```

You could even get rid of the `id` values and use `data-fruit` instead:

```
<input type="checkbox" data-fruit="pineapple" class="fruit">
```

...and then:

```
$(".fruit").click(function() {
    $("#graphic-" + $(this).attr("data-fruit")).toggle();
});
```

...but I'm not sure that buys you much over the first solution above. :-)

Comment: Wow - thanks so much for the speedy reply. I went with the first option, works perfect. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `class` with a `data` attribute to specify which element to `toggle()`. Try this:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="checkbox-orange" class="checkbox-fruit" data-related-graphic="#graphic-orange" />
```

```js
$('.checkbox-fruit').click(function() {
    $($(this).data('related-graphic')).toggle();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for this alternative solution Rory. +1